# Django get multiple coloumn using group by

Tags: python, django, orm

`TagNews.objects.filter(status=1).values("news","tag").annotate(total=Count('tag'))`

```
SELECT `tags_news`.`news_id`,
       `tags_news`.`tag_id`,
        COUNT(`tags_news`.`tag_id`) AS `total`
  FROM `tags_news`
 WHERE `tags_news`.`status` = 1
 GROUP BY `tags_news`.`news_id`,
          `tags_news`.`tag_id`
 ORDER BY NULL
```

But I want also multiple column field and single group by like as bellow query :-

```
SELECT `tags_news`.`news_id`,
       `tags_news`.`tag_id`,
        COUNT(`tags_news`.`tag_id`) AS `total`
  FROM `tags_news`
 WHERE `tags_news`.`status` = 1
 GROUP BY `tags_news`.`tag_id`
 ORDER BY NULL
```

Comment: you should edit your question and give more relevant info/code on the problem you have.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to group TagNews with `tag` then get `tag` and `news` columns.So this should work;

```
tag_news = TagNews.objects.filter(status=1).values("tag").annotate(total=Count('tag'))
tag_news.values("news","tag")
```

Comment: this is not right answer

`code`
  tag_news = TagNews.objects.filter(status=1).values("tag").annotate(total=Count('tag'))
            tag_news.values("news","tag")
            print tag_news.query

SELECT `tags_news`.`tag_id`, COUNT(`tags_news`.`tag_id`) AS `total` FROM `tags_news` WHERE `tags_news`.`status` = 1 GROUP BY `tags_news`.`tag_id` ORDER BY NULL

Comment: that did seem to me right.Could you find out the answer?